# Unsupported Mediatype Axios with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have an issue posting my data into my web api.  I always got an error `Unsupported Media Type` of some sort even though I set the `Content-type: 'application/json'` in my `axios` code.  See my implementation below:

**ServiceHelper.jsx**

```js
let instance = axios.create();
let token = 'xxxx token';
export const PostData = (url, data) => {
    var username = 'username'
    instance.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    instance.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=UTF-8';
    instance.defaults.headers.common['X-Current-Username'] = username;
    instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    instance.defaults.data = JSON.stringify(data);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        instance.post(`${config.externalApi}/${url}`).then(response => {
            if(response.data !== undefined && response.data !== null) {
                resolve(response.data);
            } else {
                reject(Error('no data found'))
            }
        })
    })
}
```

And here is the result of my network headers:

```js
// Request Headers:
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8,sv;q=0.7,de;q=0.6
Authorization: Bearer xxxtoken
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:45944
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36
X-Current-Username: username
```

I am not certain why it doesn't show any content-type in here.  Does anyone has the same issue with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is a CORS policy problem with your API. Use [npm cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package in your API as middleware.

Recently I ran into the same problem and was that simple.

Comment: ohhh forgot to mentioned that I use .net 5 for my api.  I set the CORS policy to accept `Content-Type`.  I will try to take a look into the the CORS

Comment: thanks it works now, i made a dumb mistake in the chaining with my `Startup.cs`